# Highlight epub text inside iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe, rangy

I have to upload ePub files on my webpage using iFrame. Now I want to add the functionality of highlighting user selected text inside that iFrame containing the ePub. I am currently using Rangy Library for text highlighting, and it works for the text outside of the iFrame but not for the text inside it.

Here is the code for highlighting:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<style>
    .highlight {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/rangy-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/rangy-classapplier.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/rangy-highlighter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangy/1.3.0/rangy-textrange.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var highlighter;

window.onload = function() {
rangy.init();

        highlighter = rangy.createHighlighter();
        highlighter.addClassApplier(rangy.createClassApplier("highlight", {
            ignoreWhiteSpace: true,
            tagNames: []
        }));
function highlight() {
        highlighter.highlightSelection('highlight');
 // var iframe = $("iframe")[0];
    var selTxt = rangy.getSelection(myFrame);
            console.log('selTxt: '+selTxt);
        highlighter.highlightRanges('highlight', selTxt._ranges);
}

document.getElementById('highlight').addEventListener('click', highlight);}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="highlight">Highlight</button>

    <div>select to highlight </div>
    <div>line to be highlighted</div>
    <div>line to be highlighted one </div>
        <p>Another <b>paragraph</b></p>

<iframe src="iframe.html" width=500 height=500 name="myFrame"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the iframe code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>This is iframe </h1>
  <p>Select content to highlight</p>
  <p>Select text to highlight</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This code works but only highlights the text outside of the iframe,I need it to highlight text inside the iframe.

Comment: For the highlighting part itself you could use [mark.js](https://markjs.io/) which has built-in iframe support.

Comment: My project requires serialization. Does mark.js support that? If not, could you suggest any other alternative with serialization?

Comment: Could you please specify what exactly you mean with `serialization`?

Comment: I have to convert my objects into text/binary forms for storing and transmitting over the network. Rangy supports this inherently, does mark.js support it?

Comment: Sorry, you'll need to give us an example with  your requirements. Please update your question to reflect what you need -- with a code example.

Comment: My preferred library is Rangy. So I would like to know if I can manipulate the inner iFrame using it, particularly highlighting the text inside it. Please let me know if you have any information about this. Thank you so much.

Comment: Basically serialization i am using here to store the user selection offset  so that  the user start with their selection on next visit as it is.

Comment: @dude Is `mark.js` a good option if I don't have any tags available around the text. I mean I just have a text content in the form of JSON data.

Comment: @John can you provide some code in form of a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @dude I have one of my outstanding forum question here https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/linking-document-with-words/234661  which may give you an idea about the problem/JSON data. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @John Let's switch over to this thread.

Comment: @dude I have included the fiddle on that thread.